# Square of number sequences

Tags: mathematics, number-sequence

Here is a square filled with numbers and holes.

[image]

> The square is divided in multiple invisible areas which all have their own specific logical sequence.
>   Although every numbers in an area is found with the same logic, the numbers used to find the next number can come from another area.
>   Can you find every **positive integers** missing by finding out the logical sequences?

**NOTE**
This is an new experimental puzzle for me, so let me know how it is in the comments. Hopefully it will go well.

**NOTE2**
I used the word "sequence" quite loosely here.
Some numbers might not be found by using the numbers "immediately" preceding them

**EXAMPLE**

[image]

Rule of area 1 is +1 the previous number
Rule of area 2 is 5 times the upper number
Rule of area 3 is 2 times the upper number

**HINT**
The correct solution will be found with a total of 4 areas.
The shapes of the areas are quite basic. No weird awkward shapes.

**HINT2**
All areas are of equal sizes

Comment: This seems way too broad. The left column is fine, but the rest... I'm not so sure about. It seems dangerously close to "Guess what I'm thinking".

Comment: @Deusovi Should I make the areas visible and see how it goes?

Comment: ^vote with a note: A small-scale example fully solved would be quite helpful. Could be just a few cells with only 2 areas, woudn't even need to be well-clued.

Comment: @humn I added a small example, let me know what you think. Since I made the puzzle it seems very easy to me but, perhaps not knowing where the areas are is too hard?

Comment: Excellent example, stack reader, completely clarifies the puzzle for me. 
Would be worth formatting. (The original puzzle still looks tough, but what else is new . . . a good hint might be the total number of areas.)

Comment: @stackreader By _I used the word "sequence" quite loosely here_ do you mean, you can write 1,2,3,4,5... as 1,3,4,5 ?? i.e. skipping any number from sequence?

Comment: @Techidiot It means that the resulting number will not always be the result of the preceding 2 number(2 above or 2 to the left etc). For example, the 6th number could be the result of the addition of the 1st and 3rd number of the same row.

Comment: I think the size of the areas, or at least a lower bound on their size, is necessary here.  It's trivial to divide the entire square into areas of size 1, and then come up with an individual rule for each area.  Even areas of size 2 would probably be pretty simple, and would be far from a unique solution.  If you don't want to give away the areas, perhaps give the size of each one e.g.  {2x4, 1x4, 2x3, 3x3, etc.} and the total number of areas.

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain wow, that's a good point. If someone came up with an answer with only size one area I wouldn't be able to say it's not good lol... I guess saying how many areas there are would help, or just straight out show them.(I wrote the number of areas in the question for now.)

Comment: @stackreader That's much better.  I think that will probably help narrow it to a single unique solution (or at least pretty close).

Comment: why does MathJax coloring have to override spoilers tags. :(

Comment: @Rubio maybe because in the end spoilers tags are just coloring too. And no priority has been set on them.

Comment: @stackreader apparently Spoilers operate by setting textcolor=backgroundcolor, but don't look into MathJax formatting.  so a background color setting in MathJax shows through, and the text inside it is rendered in white against it, making it quite clearly visible in the spoiler block when not hovered on.  I found an interesting solution - make the MathJax block require clicking.  That was a fun puzzle in and of itself. :)

Comment: Not sure if I should make more puzzle like this one, it was quite experimental and didn't go too well, maybe I should rethink it a little.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Equally divide the square into 4 3x3 quadrants. Top left quadrant - sum of the cell above and to the left. Bottom left - sum of all the cells above. Top right - sum of the cell 2 steps to the left and of the cell to the left. Bottom right- sum of the cell 3 steps to the left and of the cell 3 steps above. The numbers (as we fill the rows) are 0,1,2,3,5,8,1,2,4,6,10,16,2,4,8,12,20,32,3,7,14,6,12,22,6,14,28,12,24,44,12,28,56,24,48,88.
>
>  $$\require{action}\require{enclose}\toggle{\enclose{roundedbox}{\text{ Click here to toggle grid }}}{\enclose{roundedbox}{\text{ Click here to toggle grid }}\begin{array}{|c|c|}\hline\begin{array}{c}\bbox[pink]{\begin{array}{c|c|c}{\textbf0} & \textbf1 & 2  \\\hline\textbf1 & 2 & \textbf4  \\\hline\ 2\ &\ 4\ &\ \textbf8\ \end{array}}\\\hline\bbox[cyan]{\begin{array}{c|c|c}\textbf3 & \textbf7 & 14 \\\hline 6 & 14 & 28  \\\hline 12 & \textbf{28} & 56 \end{array}} \end{array} & \begin{array}{c} \bbox[yellow]{ \begin{array}{c|c|c} 3 & \textbf5 & 8   \\\hline 6 & 10 & \textbf{16} \\\hline 12 & \textbf{20} & 32 \end{array}}\\\hline \begin{array}{c|c|c} \textbf6 & 12 & 22   \\\hline 12 & \textbf{24} & 44   \\\hline 24 & 48 & \textbf{88} \end{array} \end{array} \\\hline \end{array}}\endtoggle$$

Got a lot of help for this from Angzuril and mactro's answers.

Comment: Welcome to puzzling and good job on solving this puzzle. This is exactly the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 4):

My solution (partially matching that of Angzuril):

> [image]

Yellow: sum of the cell directly above, and directly to the left (in case one cell is missing, treat it as 1)

Blue: sum of two cells directly to the left

Red: 4 times the cell 2 above

Green: Sum of cells 3 and 4 to the left. In case there is no cell 4 to the left, it's two times the 3rd cell.

Comment: Very nice try! but the logic for the "green" area seems a little bit more like 2 rules than one. Here is a hint, the numbers in the top half of the square are all good, and the blue area's logic is correct. The logic for the yellow area is also correct, but the size was not.

Comment: ^vote of approval for being the only solution with reasons for the edge cells near the top left corner

Answer (score 3):

My solution, probably not intended solution.

> [image]

Yellow: Sum of the cell directly above, and directly to the left

Blue: Double cell directly above

Green: Sum of the 2 cells to the left

Red: Form of $2 \times (a - b^2)$ , where a is 3 cells to the left, and b is 3 cells above a. The complexity of this rule leads me to believe it is not intended.

Comment: You could cheat a little and say Red is $\frac12$ of the cell directly below...  :)

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain Thanks for the edits, I would like to avoid circular references however :P

Comment: @Angzuril Very good job! But the red area logic is indeed a little bit too complex. Look at my comment to the other answer for some hints.

Answer (score 2):

my answer is,

> $$\require{action}\require{enclose}\toggle{\enclose{roundedbox}{\text{ Click here to toggle grid }}}{\enclose{roundedbox}{\text{ Click here to toggle grid }}\begin{array}{|c|c|}\hline\begin{array}{c}\bbox[pink]{\begin{array}{c|c|c}{\textbf0} & \textbf1 & 2  \\\hline\textbf1 & 2 & \textbf4  \\\hline 2 & 4& \textbf8   \\\hline \ \textbf3\  & \ \textbf7\  & 15 \end{array}}\\\hline\bbox[cyan]{\begin{array}{c|c|c}\text{-4}\ &  12\ & 28  \\\hline 12 & \textbf{28} & 44 \end{array}} \end{array} & \begin{array}{c} \bbox[yellow]{ \begin{array}{c|c|c} 3 & \textbf5 & 8   \\\hline 6 & 10 & \textbf{16} \\\hline 12 & \textbf{20} & 32 \end{array}}\\\hline \begin{array}{c|c|c} \textbf6 & 14 & 30   \\\hline \text{-8} & \textbf{24} & 56   \\\hline 24 & 56 & \textbf{88} \end{array} \end{array} \\\hline \end{array}}\endtoggle$$
>
>  Top left (pink) is sum of top and left
>  Top right (yellow) is sum of two left ones
>  Bottom left (cyan) is left +16
>  Bottom right (white) is three to the left doubled

original format:
I am not on a computer so sorry for formatting.
_ separate cells and '  separates groups, and bold is the last row in a group,

> 0_1_2'3_5_8
>  1_2_4'6_10_16.
>  2_4_8'**12_20_32**
>  **3_7_15**'6_14_30
>  -4_12_28'-8_24_56
>  12_28_44'24_56_88

Comment: I'm not sure your bottom left logic works that well.

Comment: Oops -6 should have been -4..

Comment: Otherwise I think its OK....

Comment: Sorry if it was not clearly mentioned in the question but only positive integers are expected. I will add it to the question now, along with a few more hints.(+1 for the nice try)